# Using the reduce function to return an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Why is it that when I want to use the push function inside the reduce function to return a new array I get an error. However, when I use the concat method inside the reduce function, it returns a new array with no problem.

All I'm trying to do is pass an array to the reduce function and return the same array.

```
var store = [0,1,2,3,4];

var stored = store.reduce(function(pV,cV,cI){
  console.log("pv: ", pV);
  return pV.push(cV);
},[]);
```

This returns an error. But when I use concat:

```
var store = [0,1,2,3,4];

var stored = store.reduce(function(pV,cV,cI){
  console.log("pv: ", pV);
  return pV.concat(cV);
},[]);
```

It returns the same array.

Any ideas why?

Comment: `return PV.push` means on the next iteration, PV will be a Number, not an array, because push returns the length of the array - if you want, you could do `return pV.push(cV), pV;` - though, there's no benefit except for 1 less line of code i.e. `pV.push(cV); return pV;`

Comment: if all you want to do is "copy" the array ... `var stored = store.slice();` will do

Comment: To return a new array from an array, you want `map` not `reduce`.

Comment: @Andy care to elaborate? The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) *literally* state `map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results` which seems to perfectly describe what the questioner was doing.

Comment: with .map, he'd do `var stored = store.map(function(v) { return v; });` ... which is simply `var stored = store.slice();` as mentioned above

Comment: Except `slice` gives you no ability to `console.log` each element, whare `map` does.

Comment: @Jamiec - ok ... `var stored = store.slice(); console.log(stored);`

Comment: Which will give a different result (in the console) to this. Keep arguing your non-point.

Comment: @Jamiec, `reduce` can return an array too. In fact it can return anything you want:  a string, an object...

Comment: @Andy - you can bang a nail into a wall with the heel of your shoe - but generally we prefer the right tool for the right job! Read the docs to both methods, or just read my answer below.

Comment: I was simply pointing out that your claim "To return a new array from an array, you want map not reduce" was incorrect.

Comment: @Andy - To bang a nail into a wall you want a hammer, not a shoe (Same point applies)

Comment: @JaromandaX Had the same problem, thanks for the concise and accurate answer. :)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

`push` returns the new length of the array.

What you need is the initially provided array.

So change the code as below.

```
var store = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

var stored = store.reduce(function(pV, cV, cI){
  console.log("pv: ", pV);
  pV.push(cV);
  return pV; // *********  Important ******
}, []);
```

`concat` returns the new array combining the elements of the provided array and concatenated elements. so it works.

Answer (score 42):

Just for completeness, and for the next person who happens on this question, what you're doing is typically achieved with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which, as stated in the docs

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results

Contrast that with the description of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it **to a single value**.

(Emphasis mine) So you see, although you *can* manipulate `reduce` to return a new array, it's general usage is to reduce an array to a single value.

So for your code this would be:

```
var store = [0,1,2,3,4];

var stored = store.map(function(pV){
  console.log("pv: ", pV);
  return pV;
});
```

Much simpler than trying to reconstruct a new array using either `push` or `concat` within a `reduce` function.

Comment: Sometimes, you want to do a `.filter().map()` and rather than being O(2N) you can cut the work in half by doing a single pass using `.reduce()`, keeping yourself O(N).

Comment: I assume with ECMA it will be something like `store.map(it => {return it});`?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' `store.map(it => ({it}))` will also work.

Comment: Excellent! While I think I would go with the version with a `return`, so it is easier to understand to me :)

Answer (score 26):

I know this is the same answer, but I just want to show that using `reduce ()`, the syntax can also be reduced to a single line of code using ES6:

```js
var store = [0,1,2,3,4];

var stored = store.reduce((pV,cV) => [...pV, cV], []);

console.log(stored);
```

Answer (score 4):

`reduce()` can be useful if you need to return an array with multiple items for each item iterated:

```
var inputs = media.reduce((passedArray, video) => {
    passedArray.push("-i");
    passedArray.push(video.filepath);
    return passedArray;
}, []);
```

Here it's being used to build the input array for FFmpeg;

```
[{ name: "bob", filepath: "1.mp4" }, { name: "sue", filepath: "3.mp4" }]
=> ["-i", "1.mp4", "-i", "2.mp4]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method returns the new length of the array.

[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method inserts new element into array and returns array back so it can be further processed. This is what you need to do with reduce: pass modified array the the next iteration.

Comment: But it's not the same array; `concat` allocates a new array which is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use destructuring:

```js
var store = [0,1,2,3,4];

var stored = store.reduce(function(pV,cV,cI){
  console.log("pv: ", pV);
  return [...pV, cV];
},[]);

console.log(stored);
```