# filtered.push is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am using reduce function and some reason I get an error on the console:

> (index):77 Uncaught TypeError: filtered.push is not a function

`DispatchedNumber` should exist before mapping into `Lines` array.

```
function payload(order) {
  return {
    OrderId: order.ORDERID,
    Lines: order.ITEMS.reduce(function(filtered, item) {
      if (item.DispatchedNumber != undefined) {
        var newItem = {
          Qty: item.Qty,
          QtyShipped: item.DispatchedNumber
        }

        filtered.push(newItem);
      }

      return filtered;
    })
  }
}

test = payload({
  "ORDERID": 1233,
  "ITEMS": [
    { Qty: 123, DispatchedNumber: 111 },
    { Qty: 111 },
    { Qty: 444, DispatchedNumber: 555 },
    { Qty: 443, DispatchedNumber: 323 }
  ]
})
```

Usage:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 2));
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/j6097w9d/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the reduce function to return an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431292/using-the-reduce-function-to-return-an-array)

Comment: @Luca You flagged as Duplicate which is not even close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no initial value specified for the accumulator in the reduce function.

Please update to following

```
order.ITEMS.reduce(function(filtered, item) {
      if (item.DispatchedNumber != undefined) {
        var newItem = {
          Qty: item.Qty,
          QtyShipped: item.DispatchedNumber
        }

        filtered.push(newItem);
      }

      return filtered;
    }, []) // add the empty array (initial value of accumulator)
```

For reference, [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

**Reduce Syntax**

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

You need to be initialise your `filtered` variable into [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

**DEMO**

```js
function payload(order) {
  return {
    OrderId: order.ORDERID,
    Lines: order.ITEMS.reduce(function(filtered, item) {
      if (item.DispatchedNumber != undefined) {
        var newItem = {
          Qty: item.Qty,
          QtyShipped: item.DispatchedNumber
        }
        
        filtered.push(newItem);
      }
      
      return filtered;
    },[])
  }
}

var test = payload({
  "ORDERID": 1233,
  "ITEMS": [{ Qty: 123, DispatchedNumber: 111 },{ Qty: 111 },{ Qty: 444, DispatchedNumber: 555 },{ Qty: 443, DispatchedNumber: 323 }]
})


console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {  max-height: 100% !important;  top: 0;}
```