# How can I push each item in the possibleNumber array twice into the unplacedArray in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I push each item in the `possibleNumber` array  twice into the `unplacedArray` in JavaScript?

Here's my code, but it doesn't work as desired:

```
var possibleNumbers = [1, 2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var unplacedArray = [];
for(possibleIndex = 1; possibleIndex <= possibleNumbers.length; possibleIndex++) {
   possibleNumbers[possibleIndex];
   unplacedArray.push(possibleNumbers[possibleIndex]).fill(2);
}
console.log(unplacedArray);
```

Comment: You want `unplacedArray` to be `[1,1, 2,2, 3,3,  4,4, 5,5, 6,6, 7,7, 8,8]`?

Comment: `unplacedArray.push(possibleNumbers[possibleIndex], possibleNumbers[possibleIndex]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)" and "[flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)" to achieve this

```js
var possibleNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var unplacedArray = possibleNumbers.map(d => [d,d]).flat()
console.log(unplacedArray)

// Or directly flatMap()
var possibleNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var unplacedArray = possibleNumbers.flatMap(d => [d,d])
console.log(unplacedArray)
```

Comment: Why not directly `.flatMap()` ?

Comment: Can use flatMap as well, which is sort of shorthand for this but I generally tend to work with them separately and not practise "flatMap" that's why it does not strike at the first go to me  :) Thanks for pointing though.

Answer (score 0):

Somtehing like this?

```
var possibleNumbers = [1, 2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var unplacedArray = [...possibleNumbers, ...possibleNumbers];

console.log(unplacedArray)

// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is first to use splice to create a second copy of every element into the array, and then to shuffle it, ala the post here: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as in '[Using the reduce function to return an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431292/using-the-reduce-function-to-return-an-array)' but adding your custom code inside the reduce:

```
possibleNumbers.reduce((accumulator, number) => {
    accumulator.push(number);
    accumulator.push(number);
    return accumulator
  },
  []
)
```